# Handlebar table construction

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I have a table where a handlebars template is used. In the first row of the table `#each` is declared and in the next row tokens are declared, in the last line the `#each` end declaration is done.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1"><colgroup><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">{{#each itemList}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{{price}}</td>
<td>{{qty}}</td>
<td>{{total}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">{{/each}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

After executing the compiled template, the generated output looks like below. The first row and the last row are not removed in the table where each is defined. Is there any way to remove that?

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1" data-mce-style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>v</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
         </tr>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We cannot help you with this problem without seeing JS that we can change so that it will act as you expect.

Comment: used the handlebar builtin each template  only @RAllen

Comment: You are using wrong structure to make table using each. Why do you need colspan of 4 ? can you please attach the expected output ?

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784362/using-handlebars-each-in-a-table and try to change your template in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are wrapping your `#each` call, as in `<td colspan="4">{{#each itemList}}</td>`. This will produce completely broken HTML.

You want to have a *row* `<tr>` for each item in `itemList`, so you want to make sure that the row tags `<tr>` and `</tr>` are contained by the `#each` and that any markup *outside* of the each is a valid and closed `<tr>`:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">      <colgroup><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4"></td>
     </tr>
     {{#each itemList}}
       <tr>
         <td>{{name}}</td>
         <td>{{price}}</td>
         <td>{{qty}}</td>
         <td>{{total}}</td>
       </tr>
     {{/each}}
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`);

const data = {
  itemList: [
    {
      name: 'One',
      price: 1,
      qty: 1,
      total: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Two',
      price: 2,
      qty: 2,
      total: 4
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This table needs to be rendered. But when rendered the table each is moved to the top. Check this demo link https://jsfiddle.net/ta5478rj/

Comment: @undefined_null1: The `#each` needs to go _inside_ the table, not above it.